# Flash CS5 iOS keeping player moving

Tags: iphone, flash, actionscript-3, ios, flash-cs5

I am currently using:

```
right.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchRight);
function onTouchRight (e:TouchEvent):void{
player.x += 5;
```

as my code, and I was wondering if there was a way to keep the player moving without continuously tapping the button.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways to accomplish this.  the most common approach would be to employ an [Event.ENTER_FRAME](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#ENTER_FRAME) event.  you could also fire the Event.ENTER_FRAME from the TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN event handler, or fire a timer that would call the event instead.

remember to remove your events, especially your Event.ENTER_FRAME events, when it's not being used.